# How to save/update event from dhtmlx scheduler using php

Tags: php, mysql, dhtmlx

I have downloaded dhmtlx event scheduler and able to successfully loaded data from MySQL DB. But I am not getting how to save event-related data into DB.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function init() {
var sections=[
<?php 
$data = "";
for($i=0; $i<count($employees);$i++){
    $data.='{key:<?php echo $i?>, label:"<?php echo $employees[$i]?>"}'.",",
     }
    $data = substr($data,0,-1);
    echo $data;?>
];
scheduler.locale.labels.unit_tab = "Unit"
scheduler.locale.labels.section_custom="Section";
scheduler.config.details_on_create=true;
scheduler.config.details_on_dblclick=true;
scheduler.config.lightbox.sections=[    
    {name:"description", height:50, map_to:"text", type:"textarea" , focus:true},
    {name:"custom", height:30, type:"select", options:sections, map_to:"section_id" },
    {name:"time", height:72, type:"time", map_to:"auto"}
]

scheduler.createUnitsView({
    name:"unit",
    property:"section_id",
    list:sections,
    size:10,
    step:5
});
scheduler.config.multi_day = true;
scheduler.init('scheduler_here',new Date('<?php echo date('Y')?>','<?php echo date('m')?>','<?php echo date('d')?>'),"unit");
scheduler.load("./data/units.json");
}
</script>
```

But I am not able to figure out how to insert/ update data from the event popup. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how about handling https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_oneventadded_event.html (for the insert) and similar events for update/delete? That will give you the new event data. You can then send it to the server via AJAX or whatever. I haven't seen this plugin before but it took about 20 seconds to find those events in the documentation. Have you tried them?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach to connect dhtmlxScheduler to a backend is to implement RESTful API on the server and use dhtmlxDataProcessor on the client. Please find a detailed guide in the dhtmlxScheduler documentation:

https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/server_integration.html

Comment: What is the advantage of using the dhtmlxDataProcessor instead of manually doing the calls in ajax?